# Figure with Text beneath

Tags: graphics, two-column

I am trying to place a text in single column with the text having a two column format. But the figure comes on top of the text.
How can this be solved?

Comment: Can you provide a MWE? 
And also it's a problem to put the table on the two columns or not?

Comment: The table is in the form of figure. It is included in the following forrmat
\begin{figure}[!t]
\centering
\includegraphics[width =2.0\columnwidth]{Figure 2.pdf}
\captionof{table}[foo]{ }
\label{img:foobar}
\end{figure}

Comment: Can you please tell me how to add MWE? I just copied the code.

Comment: this should probably be entered with `figure*` which specifies that the figure is to span the entire page.  it can be placed only at the top of a page, but that's what you've specified anyhow.

Comment: @user87834 --- For info on MWEs, see [this question](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/2417).